# SQL join on second table all distinct rows showing a column from both tables

Tags: sql

This might be a very simple sql however for the life of me, I can't seem to get the desired results.

For purposes of illustration, I have two tables, Table A and Table B with the following records in each table.

Thank you in advance and my apologies for the novice formatting on here.

[image: TABLE A]

[image: TABLE B]

Desired  Results

[image: Results Table]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `full join`:

```
select id, a.col1, b.col2
from a full join
     b
     using (id);
```

If your database doesn't support `full join`, I would recommend:

```
select a.id, a.col1, b.col2
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.id
union all
select b.id, null, b.col2
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.id = b.id);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. It works quite well. Now I need to be able to join other tables about 8 additional tables using your method.

Comment: @Ropeh . . . You can extend the `full join` and keep using `using`, if the join column is the same.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thank you once again for the answer to my question earlier. If it's ok to ask a followup question, supposing I have about four tables I want to combine, how do I structure the query?

Comment: @Ropeh . . . Perhaps you should ask a *new* question, with sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.